# Chef - triggering one block based on the results of another

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I wrote a simple recipe (runs on a RHEL node) that after installing a rpm package it checks if it's running by running the `service MyService status` command and I capature the results via stdout and RegEx from a ruby block

My question is if that the regex does not match hence the service is not running how can i trigger a block that says

`rpm_package 'MyService' do
   action :remove
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by making a custom resource instead of using a `ruby_block` or recipe-level code.